# How to calculate the number of immediate children for each node in an adjacency list

Tags: select, mysql, adjacency-list

I have hierarchical data that I represent using the adjacency list model.

```
TABLE
    ID
    parentID
    title
```

I am wondering, what is the simplest way to SELECT the number of immediate children for each node?  If possible, I'd like to do this in a single select, yielding a resultset like so...

```
RESULTS...
ID     title     childCount
1      test1     10
2      test2     2
3      test3     0
etc...
```

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Without the title,

```
SELECT parentID as ID, COUNT(ID) AS childCount
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY parentID
```

If you do want the title I think you need a self-join (probably way slower):

```
SELECT t1.ID as ID, t1.Title as Title, COUNT(t2.ID) as childCount
  FROM Table t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.parentID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Alex forgot 'Group By t2.parentID'

also you can try:

```
SELECT t1.ID as ID, t1.Title as Title, COUNT(t2.ID) as childCount
```

FROM Table t1 
  INNER JOIN Table t2 ON t1.ID = t2.parenID
  GROUP BY t2.parentID